# Regular Expression for input validation

Tags: regex

I am trying to learn regular expressions and was hoping someone could help me out. WOuld appreciate if someone can help me come up with a regular expression to validate that an input must be of the form

```
Graph: XY5, YZ4, ST7
```

Each part such as XY5 represents an edge in the graph and the number represents a the edge weight. There can be any number of such edges.

This is what I have till now. It's probably not correct

```
"^Graph:\\s{1}[A-ZA-Z\\d,\\s]+"
```

Comment: "it's probably not correct" - did you actually try it?

Comment: Yes I did. It said my input matches but I wasn't able to explain it to myself convincingly. So that is why I said what I did. Apologies for not making that clear.

Comment: @deathApril - That is simply wrong. Within the brackets, `0-9` and `\d` are exactly the same. However, since he has many other things in there, all of them become optional: `/[a-z\d]/` will match either a character or a digit, but definitely no a slash!

Comment: @JosephSilber sorry for my confusion, i deleted the comment - it will match a backslash or d in **POSIX** (Ereg) implementation (e.g. Oracle) , but it will match a digit in **PCRE** (Preg) or Javascript implementation, see [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: @deathApril - Sorry for my [ignorance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). I work with PHP/JavaScript all day long, and have simply forgotten about POSIX. Thanks for pointing that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
/^Graph: (?:[A-Z]{2}\d(?:$|, ?))+/
```

See it here in action: http://regexr.com?309av

---

Here's an explanation of what the regex does (screenshot from [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), which is probably the best tool for you if you're trying to learn Regular Expressions):

[image]

Comment: for the ones "trying to learn", `(?:aaa)` [turns off capturing the backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) and is not supported in all languages...

Comment: did you consider putting $ at the end? so it won't match `Graph: XY5, ` from `"Graph: XY5, something incorrect"`

Comment: @deathApril - Was considering it, but the OP's request was too ambiguous, so I wasn't sure whether he'd want to match that.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain your input format a little better.  This might do it, from the single example I have and what you said.  It does not allow a graph to be empty, which may or may not be part of your requirements.

```
"^Graph:(\s\w{2}\d+,?)+"
```

to explain:

`^Graph:` will cover the start of the line

```
(\s\w{2}\d+,?)+
```

`\s` is a space

`\w{2}` matches exactly 2 alphanumeric characters (hint: you could make this better!)

`\d+` matches 1 or more digits, since I am assuming an edge can have a two digit length ( such as 10)

`,?` matches a comma optionally.  (hint: you could make this better as well, as it will not necessitate a comma between each entry!, maybe by using an or and the end of string delimiter!)

I purposely left some room for improvement, because if you think of some of it on your own, you will accomplish your goal of becoming better with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/^Graph:(\s+[A-Z][A-Z]\d+)+$/
```